# MongoDB - how to receibed only 1 fields of Array field in $filter results

Tags: mongodb, filter

I am creating a view, after doing the filter I receive all the fields of the array, how can I tell the $filter to only return 1 fields?

```
db.createView(
  "vPendientes",
  "instancedb",
  [
  {
    $project: {
    "Actividad" : {
                     $filter : { input : "$tasks", cond : { $eq: [ "$$this.status" , "Received"]  } }
                  },
```

Comment: You can use `$map` after or before the filter

Comment: $slice can help:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126289/how-to-slice-a-filter-result-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with a $map, the correct final code is:

```
db.createView(
  "vPendientes",
  "instancedb",
  [
  {
    $project: {
    "Actividad" : {
                    $map : {
                      input : {
                        $slice:[{
                          $filter : { input : '$tasks', as : "t", cond : {$eq: [ "$$t.status" , "Received"]  } }
                        },-1]
                      }, 
                      as : "tmp", 
                      in: {"status": "$$tmp.status"}
                    }
                  },
```